# Jquery modification .change script to include .val

Tags: jquery, onchange

I'm new to jquery and need a hand modifying a script that calculates the price based on the current quantity. The price changes when the user changes the quantity, but the quantity can also change with another script using .val. From the documentation I've read .change does not detect .val events.

Similar questions I've read suggest using .trigger following .val to fire off the change event. **The problem is that I don't fully understand how to implement this into my script properly.**

```
$('.qty').val(this.value).trigger('change');
```

Here's the script I'm using to dynamically change the price based on the product quantity:

```
jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
                        cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        $('#cart_total_price .price').html( currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));

                });
            });
```

**Input:**

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="1000" max="" name="quantity" value="1000" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you changing the quantity?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Usually the user would change the quantity value in a number input by typing a different value, but I need this price script to include changes to the quantity by a jquery range slider using .val as well.

Comment: You need to add the script in change event of slider as well.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar The entire function I have above or just a portion?

Comment: In change event of slider.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Right, but do i need to add the entire script I have posted above in the change event of the slider or just a portion?

Comment: just a portion that sets the value and trigger change event.